# How to fix "Error: Unknown option: devServer" in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, vue-cli, vuejs3

I tried to add a `devServer` configuration into the *babel.config.js* file (Vue 3 project) and I get this error.  Even when I copy the original code from the [official site](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy), it still reports this error.

The error:

```
Error: Unknown option: .devServer. Check out https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-core/#options for more information about options.
at throwUnknownError (/Users/aman/Desktop/Vue/vue01/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/validation/options.js:124:27)
at /Users/aman/Desktop/Vue/vue01/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/validation/options.js:109:5
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at validateNested (/Users/aman/Desktop/Vue/vue01/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/validation/options.js:85:21)
at validate (/Users/aman/Desktop/Vue/vue01/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/validation/options.js:76:10)
at /Users/aman/Desktop/Vue/vue01/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:200:34
at cachedFunction (/Users/aman/Desktop/Vue/vue01/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/caching.js:62:27)
at cachedFunction.next (<anonymous>)
at evaluateSync (/Users/aman/Desktop/Vue/vue01/node_modules/gensync/index.js:251:28)
at sync (/Users/aman/Desktop/Vue/vue01/node_modules/gensync/index.js:89:14)error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

How can I fix this error "Unknown option: .devServer"

Comment: yes I use vue cli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a Vue CLI project, your Webpack configuration goes in *vue.config.js* in your project root, not *babel.config.js*.  If that file doesn't exist, you should create it and put your `devServer` configuration in it.

From [the docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js):

> vue.config.js is an optional config file that will be automatically loaded by @vue/cli-service if it's present in your project root (next to package.json). You can also use the vue field in package.json, but do note in that case you will be limited to JSON-compatible values only.

***vue.config.js***  (Not *babel.config.js*)

```js
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    // Your configuration goes here
  }
}
```